# c# Set the value of combobox and texbox in the same foreach loop

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox, textbox, foreach

I have an array of textboxs and comboboxes which I want to set their value against a loop I have going. preinput1 and postinput1 are textboxes however, preinput5 and postinput5 are comboboxes. The error being trying to refer to a combobox as textbox : "TextBox tb" .

```
    var StringInput = new object[] { preInput1, preInput5, postInput1, postInput5};
    int stringCount1 = 0;
    int toto = (ArrayCount + StringInput.Length);

    foreach (TextBox tb in StringInput)
    {
      tb.Text = Convert.ToString(energyCalculation.Cells[place[xCSV]].Value);
      xCSV++;
      //stringCount1++;
      ArrayCount++;
    }
```

I want to avoid breaking it up to work through it one by one. What else can I write instead of TextBox, or is there a better way.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var StringInput = new Control[] { preInput1, preInput5, postInput1, postInput5};
int stringCount1 = 0;
int toto = (ArrayCount + StringInput.Length);

foreach (var c in StringInput)
{
  c.Text = Convert.ToString(energyCalculation.Cells[place[xCSV]].Value);
  xCSV++;
  //stringCount1++;
  ArrayCount++;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I actually only changed your declare for c from 'var c' to 'Control c' and it worked as well!

Comment: @Pat That is good. The reason to change the array type to `Control[]` rather than `object[]` was to stop any other kind of object which isn't of type 'Control' being added and therefore creating the same problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (object control in StringInput)
{
  var value = Convert.ToString(energyCalculation.Cells[place[xCSV]].Value);

  var textBox = control as TextBox;
  if (textBox != null)
  {
    textBox.Text = value;
  }
  else
  {
    var comboBox = control as ComboBox;
    if (comboBox != null)
    {
      comboBox.Text = value;
    }
  }

  xCSV++;
  //stringCount1++;
  ArrayCount++;
}
```